# Beautiful Soup findAll not counting all divs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'index.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html))
print len(soup.findAll('div'))
```

where the file `index.html` is the source code of this [shopping webpage](http://shop.coles.com.au/online/SearchDisplay?multiSearch=&showResultsPage=true&langId=-1&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&browseView=true&pageSize=20&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10572&pageView=image&urlLangId=-1&categoryId=449585&storeId=10503#pageNumber=1&currentPageSize=100).

My code shows that only 1 `div` tag was found. But what's weirder is `findAll('a')` returns a huge (so probably correct) number. `span` works etc, but not `div`.

Comment: Kind of found a 'fix'...using bs3 worked :(

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the [differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) that `BeautifulSoup` uses under-the-hood.

Choose either `html.parser`, or `html5lib`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = 'index.html'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html), 'html')
>>> len(soup.findAll('div'))
0
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html), 'lxml')
>>> len(soup.findAll('div'))
0
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html), 'html.parser')
>>> len(soup.findAll('div'))
774
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html), 'html5lib')
>>> Alen(soup.findAll('div'))
774
```

Note that if you don't [specify a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), `BeautifulSoup` would pick it up automatically:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

Comment: I'm still only getting one when I use html.parser (I tried this from another SO question!), but it seems like it's working for you. weird

Comment: @javatripping ok, what about `html5lib`?

Comment: throws an error suggesting it's not installed (even after I `pip install` it?)

Comment: @javatripping yup, you should have it installed. Make sure you've installed it to the same python environment you are running it in.